# Show only a list item per registration

Tags: laravel

I have the code below to show the next registrations of a user in a conference:

```
$nextRegistrations = $user->registrations()
          ->with('participants.registration_type')
          ->whereHas(
              'conference',
              function ($query) {
                  $query->where('end_date', '>', now());
              }
          )->paginate($pageLimit);
```

Then, in the view I want to show for each registration a link "Get certificate" if the column "available_certificate" of the "registration_types" table has the value "Y". So I have the code below but there is an issue when a registration has more than 1 participant, for example if the registration has 2 participants associated with it, it appears two list items and not only one list item. Do you know how to solve that?

```
<ul class="list-group events-list">
@foreach($nextRegistrations as $nextRegistration)
    @foreach($nextRegistration->participants as $participant)
        @if(!empty($nextRegistration->conference) || !empty($nextRegistration->conference->start_date))
                @if (($participant->registration_type->certificate_available == 'Y')                                                                
                <a href="{{route('conferences.certificateInfo',
                [
                'regID'=> $nextRegistration->id])}}"
                       class="btn btn-primary ml-2">Download certificate</a>
                @endif
            </li>
        @endif
    @endforeach
@endforeach

</ul>
```

Comment: Where does the value of $temp,$k get set...? your code might in too incomplete for an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it's showing a list item for each valid participant because that's what you're asking it to do. You have a `foreach` loop, that says when a participant is valid, it should show a list item. If you want to show a single list item per registration, your code would need to changed. I would suggest adding the list item code to the first `foreach` loop and checking each participant, as soon as you find a valid participant, you can move out of `foreach` loop. See my example:

```
<ul class="list-group events-list">
    @foreach($nextRegistrations as $nextRegistration)
        @php
            $validRegistration = false;
        @endphp

        @foreach($nextRegistration->participants as $participant)
            @if(!empty($nextRegistration->conference) || !empty($nextRegistration->conference->start_date))
                @if (($participant->registration_type->certificate_available == 'Y')                                                                
                    @php
                        $validRegistration = true;
                    @endphp

                    @break
                @endif
            @endif
        @endforeach

        @if($validRegistration)
            <li><a href="{{ route('conferences.certificateInfo', ['regID' => $nextRegistration->id]) }}" class="btn btn-primary ml-2">Download certificate</a></li>
        @endif
    @endforeach
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks, but like that there is other issue, when a registration has more than 1 participant, for example if the registration has 2 participants associated with it, it appears two list items and not only one list item. Do you know how to solve that, how to show only 1 list item idependently of the number of participants associated with that registration?

Comment: That's what this does. If your registration has multiple participants, it shouldn't show multiple items. This code will only show one list item per registration.